# How to properly set my constraints?

Tags: ios, constraints, uistoryboard

I'm trying to set my constraints properly so I will get the result shown in this storyboard: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zEznC.jpg

With suggested constraints, I get this : https://i.stack.imgur.com/aOPpF.jpg

Which exact constraints should I be setting to make the picture and the two labels stay in place ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the suggested constraints, only causes trouble. Looks like you need the image to be constrained to left side, top and bottom, with aspect ratio constraint. Headline and author should then be constrained to the image on the leading side and the edge of the cell on the trailing side; also the top and bottom and you're set.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was going for but there always seemed to be something missed. And then at one point, I just moved things around a bit, decided to click "add missing constraints" (I had no constraints on at that point, or not many), and it just worked...